# Integrate chatbot with angular 8 application

Tags: python, angular, nltk, chatbot

I think this mayn't be the right platform for my question. but would like to take inputs. We have developed a chatbot using Python NTLK and tested with Tinker so far.

Would like to integrate this with our existing GUI developed on Angular 8.

How a typical architecture works for GUI to Python based app. do we need to use websockets etc?

Are there any libraries that we can leverage on Angular side.

Appreciate any ideas.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make use of dash or flask.  They are python front ends